# I want to post 'materials' from a Google Sheet to individual students in a Google Classroom

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-classroom

Using apps script in Google Sheet I can create a new assignment or 'materials' for all students in a Google Classroom. The materials are generated from a row of cells in Google Sheets. I want to post different materials for different students. In effect, each row of information will create a new materials post in Google Classroom based on the name of the student in each row. This name matches a student name in the Google Classroom.

I wrote code to retrieve the Student ID from Google Classroom

```
function getStudentId(studentName) {
  var students = Classroom.Courses.Students.list("Course ID").students;
  for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    if (students[i].profile.name.fullName === studentName) {
      return students[i].userId;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

and assign the created materials to this student, as part of the code generating the materials in Google Classroom

```
      Classroom.Courses.CourseWorkMaterials.create(materials, courseId, {assigneeMode: "INDIVIDUAL_STUDENTS", individualStudentsOptions: {studentIds: [getStudentId(pupil)]}});
```

This throws an error - GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to classroom.courses.students.list failed with error: Requested entity was not found.

I don't know if the error is in my code or if it is a permissions thing. I have added Classroom and Drive APIs to the Apps Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- It seems that the arguments of `Classroom.Courses.CourseWorkMaterials.create` is `resource: Classroom_v1.Classroom.V1.Schema.CourseWorkMaterial` and `courseId: string`. But, in your script, 3 arguments of `materials`, `courseId`, `{assigneeMode: "INDIVIDUAL_STUDENTS", individualStudentsOptions: {studentIds: [getStudentId(pupil)]}}` are used. Although I'm not sure about the value of your `materials`, I guessed that this might be the reason for your current issue.
- And, in your request body of `{assigneeMode: "INDIVIDUAL_STUDENTS", individualStudentsOptions: {studentIds: [getStudentId(pupil)]}}`, it is required to include `title` property. Please be careful about this.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
Classroom.Courses.CourseWorkMaterials.create(materials, courseId, {assigneeMode: "INDIVIDUAL_STUDENTS", individualStudentsOptions: {studentIds: [getStudentId(pupil)]}});
```

#### To:

```
Classroom.Courses.CourseWorkMaterials.create({ assigneeMode: "INDIVIDUAL_STUDENTS", individualStudentsOptions: { studentIds: [getStudentId(pupil)] }, title: "sample title" }, courseId);
```

- When this script is run, I confirmed that the user of `getStudentId(pupil)` gets an email.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your values of `courseId` and `getStudentId(pupil)` are valid values and you have permission for using this API. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Method: courses.courseWorkMaterials.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWorkMaterials/create)

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I adapted your code -    `code`   Classroom.Courses.CourseWorkMaterials.create({
        assigneeMode: "INDIVIDUAL_STUDENTS",
        individualStudentsOptions: { studentIds: [studentId] },
        title: pupil + " - " + curriculumArea,
        description: materials.description // Pass the description to the create method
      }, courseId); `code`